# Square box welding with T joint, welded with stick welding

Tags: structures, welding

When joining two square box beams in Tee, is it enough to weld them in only three sides or I have to weld the full perimeter of the square?
If those 3 sided weld are suppose to bear weight, how much of a structural strength difference can I expect from 3 sided weld vs weld on all four sides?

I had welders that did the welding with only 3 sides and I think that they are slacking off or does 3 or 4 sides not make a huge difference on the strength.

Thank you

Comment: Which 3 sides? How will the joint be loaded?

Comment: Full penetration? X-ray? Steel ? Micro-alloyed ( TMCP) can produce very strong welds.